# Finishing a forked process blocks SBT with a custom output strategy

Tags: sbt

In SBT, I fork a Java process with:

```
class FilteredOutput extends FilterOutputStream(System.out) {
    var buf = ArrayBuffer[Byte]()
    override def write(b: Int) {
        buf.append(b.toByte)
        if (b == '\n'.toInt)
            flush()
    }

    override def flush(){
        if (buf.nonEmpty) {
            val arr = buf.toArray
            val txt = try new String(arr, "UTF-8") catch { case NonFatal(ex) ⇒ "" }
            if (!txt.startsWith("pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for"))
                out.write(arr)
            buf.clear()
        }
        super.flush()
    }
}

var process = Option.empty[Process]
process = Some(Fork.java.fork(ForkOptions(outputStrategy = new FilteredOutput()), Seq("my.company.MyClass")))
```

as a result of a custom task.

Later on, I terminate it with:

```
process.map { p =>
    log info "Killing process"
    p.destroy()
}
```

by means of another custom task.
The result is that SBT doesn't accept more input and gets blocked.  Ctrl+C is the only way of restoring control back, but SBT dies as a consequence.

The problem has to do with the custom output strategy, that filters some annoying messages.

With `jstack` I haven't seen any deadlock.

SBT version 0.13.9.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to avoid closing System.out:

```
class FilteredOutput extends FilterOutputStream(System.out) {
    var buf = ArrayBuffer[Byte]()
    override def write(b: Int) {
       ...
    }

    override def flush(){
       ...
    }

    override def close() {}
}
```